# Avoid using an item in style

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a style for a button bar. some thing like this:

```
 <style name="Register.LayoutButtons">
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1.0</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Its OK for most of usage but in 1 place i don't need the `layout_marginTop`.
How can i cancel its effect without using a new style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the resource where you set the style of an item, you can also set [`layout_marginTop="0dp"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_marginTop). Or if you do it dynamically there should be a setter - for example [`setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html#setMargins(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

Comment: btw, you use it on ViewGroups, right? Views don't support margins, according to this - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#SizePaddingMargins (check the last paragraph on this section)

Comment: its a `LinearLayout` and its parent is a `LinearLayout` too! I use this structure in other place and the margin is ok . just in this case i want to remove this 16dp margin

Comment: sry, can't think of anything else atm

Comment: sorry , its resolve it :D i forgot to remove `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` !